# Django "xxxxxx Object" display customization in admin action sidebar

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I would like to change the default behavior of how the admin recent changes sidebar displays the name of "objects" added. Refer to the picture below:

[image: In the recent actions module, it also shows new objects as "MyModelName object"]

I would like to change how these are named in the Admin. Ideally, I would like to be able to change it from "MyModelName object" to, as in the "Policy" object example, something like "Policy: {{ value of the policy's "Policy Name" field. }}.

I was thinking that `__unicode__` for my Patient model handled this, but it doesn't appear to. Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: `__unicode__` does do that. Paste your code so we can see what's wrong

Comment: `__unicode__` did not work for me in Python 3. However, `__str__` did work as documented in the answer below

Answer (score 191, accepted):

`__unicode__` does do that. Your model should look something like this:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
       return 'Policy: ' + self.name
```

On Python 3 you need to use `__str__`:

```
def __str__(self):
   return 'Policy: ' + self.name
```

Comment: I foolishly didn't notice that I'd declared unicode methods for every model EXCEPT this one. :doh: Sorry all.

Comment: @patrickn, thanks for this foolish decision you made 9 years ago. :)

Answer (score 31):

Using the `__str__` method works on Python3 and Django1.8:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'MyModel: {}'.format(self.name)
```

Comment: This solved for me as well. I also use Python3 and Django1.8.

Comment: __str__ is the old way.....yet python 3 with Django, the new way (__unicode__) does not work?

Answer (score 14):

The string you're seeing is coming from `__unicode__` method, as others have mentioned. But the thing is that admin saves string representation of an object when it creates log event, therefore if you add `__unicode__` implementation after the log entry was saved, you won't see new titles on old items, only after you make some new activity

Comment: I was just wondering why the Actions log wasn't showing up the names after I set __unicode__ - I should of known it was just a log stored in the db taking data at the time of creation!

Comment: thank you, would've given me a big hassle if you hadn't explained that

Answer (score 7):

The answers mentioning `__str__` and `__unicode__` methods are correct. As stated in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/python3/#str-and-unicode-methods) however, since version 1.6 (I think), you can use the `python_2_unicode_compatible` decorator for **both** Python 2 and Python 3:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class MyClass(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return "Instance of my class"
```

You can use the above in non-`Model` objects as well.

Answer (score 6):

This would work, using def **str**(self): which returns self.title

Use something like:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to define, which column that you want to display...

for example:

```
class POAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('qty', 'cost', 'total')
```

Answer (score 2):

You're right in thinking that `__unicode__` does that. I have this running right now:

```
class Film(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ...
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

When I look in the recent actions list, I see the title of the film that I have just edited.

Answer (score 2):

By adding  `__str__()` method to the model `Patient` this way:

```
class Patient(models.Model):
name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
#.........
def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

will display name of patient instead object. For detail check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial02/)

Answer (score 1):

Since this question is 6 years old, a lot of things have changed. Let me make an update to it.With python3.6 and the latest version of Django (2.1.2) you should always use `__str__()` in new code. `__unicode__()` is an old story for python2.7 because in python3, `str` is `unicode`.