# how to change admin field name in django, python

Tags: python, django

I added one model **Author** in models.py file in my app and created model names for the author while I opened in admin panel it's showing as Author object(12) how can I change that?

I tried to add Unicode

```
class Author(models.Model):
    author_name=models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

I want field name instead of Author object in the admin panel.
[image]
below i want change Author Object

Comment: Override the `__str__()` method in your `Author` class, that's what's used by python 3 when you `print` an object. Make it a habit to always override `__str__` for all your models.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django "xxxxxx Object" display customization in admin action sidebar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336463/django-xxxxxx-object-display-customization-in-admin-action-sidebar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can overrride `__str__` method in django model class like that

```
class Author(models.Model):
    author_name=models.CharField(max_length=300)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.author_name
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    author_name=models.CharField(max_length=300)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.author_name
```

Follow what @dirkgroten said "Make it a habit to always override **str** for all your models"

---

Also You can use `list_display` method in  your `admin.py` to achieve similar result. Create a admin class and use `list_display` to render fields of model in tabular format

`Admin.py`

```
from app.models import Artist      #<-----Import you artist model 

@admin.register(Artist)          #<----- admin class should be just below this line
class ArtistAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ["id", "author_name"]
```

**Or you can also do this:**

```
from app.models import Artist      #<-----Import you artist model 


class ArtistAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["id", "author_name"]

admin.site.register(Artist, ArtistAdmin)    #<----register your class also
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example of overriding `__str__` method for cases like yours.

```
class Language(models.Model):
    language = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    class Meta:
        app_label = "languages"
        ordering = ["-modified"]

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.language} (language {self.id})"
```

Comment: :-D okay. you forgot `BaseModel' and model Class name!